# How can I create a extended class while accessing the private variables and methods of the original class?

Tags: java, automation, bots, awt, awtrobot

java version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18 LTS

I'm creating a bot to play a game; in the game, you have to click/press a key to jump; there is a set pattern that you need to jump, and I have the code for that already written.

My problem is that despite using busy-wait timers to wait until the precise microsecond (actually nanosecond, with a granularity of 100-400ns), my bot has a variable time at which it clicks.
I performed many tests and discovered that the `robot.mousePress()` method takes around 22 milliseconds on average to execute, which is unacceptable for my purposes.

The plan, therefore, was to override that method

*Robot.java*:

```java
...
public synchronized void mousePress(int buttons) {
    checkButtonsArgument(buttons);
    peer.mousePress(buttons);
    afterEvent();
}
...
```

and perform a click without things like button-mask checking and other unnecessary code that takes extra time; however, I don't know how to access the

```java
peer.mousePress(buttons);
```

method.

I tried extending the Robot class and overriding mousePress

```java
public class FastRobot extends Robot
{
    public FastRobot() throws AWTException 
    {
        super();
    }

    
    @Override
    public synchronized void mousePress(int buttons) 
    {
        System.out.println("fake click");
    }
}
```

which works, but because **peer** is a private variable, so I can't use it or call any of its methods.

I tried using the **getDeclaredVariables** and  **getDeclaredMethods** functions, but neither allowed me to call the **mousePress(buttons)** function of **peer**.

I tried creating my own

```java
private RobotPeer peer;
```

by copying what was in *Robot.java*, but Eclipse could neither specifically

```java
import java.awt.peer;
```

nor

```java
import sun.awt.AWTPermissions;
import sun.awt.ComponentFactory;
import sun.awt.SunToolkit;
import sun.awt.image.SunWritableRaster;
import sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment;
```

I'm stumped on what to do; any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You can't, not directly. Though I would expect reflection to work for you (you'd probably need some `--add-opens` arguments if you're on Java 9+).

Comment: You could use a delegate - basically a `FastRobot` would have a `Robot` as a field, and expose any methods that it needs just by having its own implementation that calls the method on the field.